# How get all data if field in query string is empty Node and Sequelize with Postgres

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

i'm studing Sequelize with Node, and i have a question..

I have the follow URL with params:

> http://localhost:9000/api/get/Joao/""

The first parameter is `name` and the second is `manager`, respectively `Joao`and `""` (i'm considering like empty)..

What i want is:
If the second parameter is `empty` i want to get all data that has the `name` Joao..

Already put `undefined, null`in the code of the `Sequelize` but not working..

Someone could help me, please?

My code of `Sequelize`:

```js
getCubikMembers(req, res) {
  return Cubik
    .findAll({
      where: {
        name: req.params.name,
        manager: null // what i put here to happen what i want?
      }
    })
    .then(success => res.status(201).send(success))
    .catch(err => res.status(err).send(err))
}
```

My api:

```js
app.get('/api/get/:name/:manager',CubikersController.getCubikMembers);
```

Answer (score 1):

i got to do, but i have that to change the `""` to `undefined`, i dont know but the value empty is different in Sequelize..

My code was:

```js
where: {
  name: req.params.name === 'undefined' ? {
    [Op.ne]: 'undefined'
  } : req.params.name,
  manager: req.params.manager === 'undefined' ? {
    [Op.ne]: 'undefined'
  } : req.params.manager
},
```

Like this if some field is `undefined` it is ignored in the filter..

I hope to have helped someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use or statement. I think possible solution would be like below. I have not tested the code.

```js
getCubikMembers(req, res) {
  const manager = req.params.manager;
  return Cubik
    .findAll({
      where: {
        [Op.or]: [
          {manager: manager ? manager : null },
          {name: req.params.name }
        ]
      }
    })
    .then(success => res.status(201).send(success))
    .catch(err => res.status(err).send(err))
}
```

Here is the docs for operators in sequelizejs.

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html#complex-filtering-or-not-queries

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, but not working, it give me all, same i puting the value in `manager`

Comment: Opps i made a type, updated the snippet, could you change the following lines like this and try again. `[Op.or]: [
          { name: req.params.name },
          {manager: req.params.manager},
        ]`

Comment: Hello, continue samething :(

Comment: It actually writes some query like `SELECT * FROM something WHERE manager = null OR name = "something"` it should be working logically

Comment: Ahh i see, you want to check name if the manager does not exists, it returns everything because it is checking the name everytime, and returns everything depending on that name. Could you please change the order of or statements? I will be updating the snippet again. I am sorry about that

Comment: Ohh yes, sure, example:

If the value of the `manager` for equal the "" i want everything that the `name` is Joao, but if i pass a value to `manager` i want an only data

Comment: In other words, I want to 'enable' the `manager` filter if it is different from ''

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182180/discussion-between-halil-irmak-and-jota).